# How to understand this kind of function declaration?

Tags: c, function

Can anyone suggest me what is the below line of code stands for?

```
static int(*pfcn[2]) (char *, ...) = { (void *)printf, (void *)NULL };
```

Comment: the initializer should be a constant; this is not a constant initializer.

Comment: sorry, i didn't read it correctly. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[C gibberish ↔ English](http://www.cdecl.org) is a nice site that helps explain declarations

```
// declare pfcn as array 2 of pointer to function (pointer to char, ...) returning int
int(*pfcn[2]) (char *, ...)
```

`{ (void *)printf, (void *)NULL };` initializes this array with the function `printf()` and then `NULL`, likely to to indicate the end.

```
int printf(const char *format, ...)
NULL
```

The `static` means the array is local and accessible only to the function/C file it is in.

---

[@Lundin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34137467/how-to-understand-this-kind-of-function-declaration/34137636#comment56023386_34137636) recommends which compiles well.

```
 // { printf, (void *) NULL };
 { printf, NULL };
```

---

IMO, also the declaration should be

```
//                    const added
static int(*pfcn[2]) (const char *, ...) = { printf, NULL };
```

Note: Some C may not allow casting a `NULL` to a function pointer.  In that case code could use

```
static int printf_null(const char *format, ...) {
  return 0;
}

static int(*pfcn[2]) (const char *, ...) = { printf, printf_null };
```

... and test against  `printf_null` rather than `NULL` to detect the end.  Avoiding casts is a good thing.

Comment: That site is not particularly nice since it fails on the variable argument list when I try it: [see this](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=int%28*pfcn[2]%29+%28char+*%2C+...%29).

Comment: @Lundin  Agree, hence the weasel words, " helps".  Not too bad for a free site.

Comment: Btw you can convert between null pointers and function pointers, it is well-defined behavior. However, in standard C you cannot convert between function pointers and regular pointers (such as `void*` in the question).

Answer (score 4):

`pfcn` is an array of function pointers.

The functions are those which take a variable number of args while returning an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

It is a (hard to read) definition of an array of two functions. I would write it something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef int (*Function)(const char *format, ...);

static Function pfcn[2] = {printf, NULL};
```

The dots mean that the function will accept zero or more arguments after the first one.